# Android: How do you delete a folder starts with period

Tags: android, file-io

I am trying to delete a folder in sdcard.
I can delete normal directories, but a directory that starts with period cannot be deleted.
(ex. ".helloDir")

```
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
```

children is null if dir starts with period (ex. ".helloDir").

Comment: maybe because its hidden, try renaming it 'exclude the dot'

Comment: children is null? So you can't even get a list of the directories if there's a dot? Or do you mean children[i] is null?

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out loud here....

The developer docs say about list()

> "Returns an array of strings with the
>   file names in the directory
>   represented by this file. The result
>   is null if this file is not a
>   directory.

Android may not think it is a directory because it is hidden, or possibly categorizes it in a different way....sounds fishy, but if your code works the way you say it does.

You might need to perform an `isHidden()` on the directory and use an alternate method to delete it.  You also might try using `listFiles()` instead of `list()`.